# matlab urlread, webread and websave fail to connect to any url

Tags: matlab

I am trying to download a web page using Matlab webread function but it gives me the error :
Error connecting to http://www.bing.com: Failed to connect to tonec.com port 59144: Connection refused

the same thing happens when I want to use websave to save files.

the point is when I was using this code in Matlab 2016a there wasn't any problem but upgrading to 2019b version this error happens.

```
filename = sprintf('%s.csv', nemad);
url = ['http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/Export-txt.aspx?t=i&a=1&b=0&i=' ii];
opts = weboptions('UserAgent','Mozilla/5.0');
record_site = websave(filename,url,opts);
```

As shown in the code, I tried to set useragent but nothing happend.

using urlread function the following error occurs: 
Error downloading URL. Your network connection may be down or your proxy settings improperly configured.

I don't use any proxy and I can see the webpages and download the file with the above url without any problem in my browser.

Comment: I remember to say: I tested webread by http://www.bing.com so in the error you see this url.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. you can edit your question.

Comment: strangely the problem gone away. I had tried to run Matlab as administrator before but it didn't work. but another time I closed it and rerun it as administraitor and now no problem with webread, websave and urlread.